# Saving and Loading a Class to a File

Tags: python, class, pickle

I'm making a text based game to better learn python. I made some classes, and I want to code a save state for the game. I could write/read every attribute of each class to a file individually, but obviously that's a hassle. I've used pickle, but I have the save/load in different functions, so pickle works in the function, but when it kicks back to the main, the class reverts back to before the load. So 2 questions: 1. Is there a way to prevent the class from reverting using pickle? Or 2: Is there a way to simplify `file.write(class)`?

Here's the code I've been testing with. I've simplified the main so it could be easy to change the attributes and check to see if the load worked properly.

```
class game:
    def __init__(self, position, coins):
        self.position = position
        self.coins = coins

player = game("start", 10)

#save w/ pickle - works
def save():
    save = input("Enter name: ")
    with open(save + ".txt", "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(player, file)

#save w/o pickle - works, would require a LOT of code
def save():
    save = input("Enter name: ")
    with open(save + ".txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(player.position)
        #file.write(<other attributes>)

#load w/ pickle - player class doesn't transfer out of function
def load():
    try:
        load = input("Enter name: ")
        with open(load + ".txt", "rb") as file:
            player = pickle.load(file)
            print(player.position)
            print(player.coins)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File doesn't exist.")

#load w/o pickle - works, would require a LOT of code
def load():
    try:
        load = input("Enter name: ")
        with open(load + ".txt", "rb") as file:
            player.position = file.read()
            #will need to modified to read each line separately
            print(player.position)
            print(player.coins)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File doesn't exist.")

a = ""
while a.lower() != "exit":
    a = input("Enter input: ")
    if a.lower() == "save":
        save()
    elif a.lower() == "load":
        load()
    elif a.lower() == "p":
        player.position = "pond"
        print(player.position)
    elif a.lower() == "b":
        player.position = "bridge"
        print(player.position)
    elif a.lower() == "s":
        player.position = "start"
        print(player.position)
    elif a.lower() == "print":
        print(player.position)
        print(player.coins)
    elif a.lower() == "-":
        player.coins -= 1
        print(player.coins)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot that you need to understand here to write code properly and simply answering the question as is won't fix it. I marked a duplicate that I *hope* will be most useful for you, but it's better if you re-read the language tutorial, or whatever source you're learning from, and make sure you understand how local and global variable scopes work.

Comment: I've been trying to stay away from global variables because I heard they're bad to use. But I'll still read up on them.

Comment: Don't use variables from an outer scope if you don't need to. Your `save` function should get the player with a parameter: `def save(player):`. Your `load` function should return the new `player` instance with `return player`, so that you can call it with `player = load()`.

Comment: BTW, the naming in your code is confusing. Why is `player` an instance of `game`? A _player_ and a _game_ are different things. According to the naming conventions in the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) the class name should start with an uppercase letter. After you fixed that your variable should be called `game` or the class should be called `Player`.

Comment: I tried ```return player``` before the (asking the) question, but the same thing. I forgot about passing parameters into functions, so I could give that a try.

Comment: As far as the naming convention, I haven't read any books or anything. I've just been learning through tutorials on youtube and various forums. I'll keep that in mind for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, yes, you indeed should not use a global for this task (which `player` currently is). But you also should understand how the scopes work, in addition to understanding how function calls work.

Comment: I found a way without global (using ```player = load()```). Thank you for the help and redirecting me.